# Celery daemonization: celery.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/celery: No such process

Tags: celery, daemon, systemd

When I do `journalctl -f` after `systemctl start celery.service` I get

```
Mar 21 19:14:21 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 21 19:14:21 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon. 
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[21431]: celery.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/celery: No such process
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting celery service...
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=217
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start celery service.
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 21 19:14:25 ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is my celery.service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=celery service
After=network.target

[Service]
#PIDFile=/run/celery/pid
Type=forking
User=celery
Group=celery
#RuntimeDirectory=celery  
WorkingDirectory=/home/mike/movingcollage
ExecStart=/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/celery multi start 3 -A movingcollage "-c 5 -Q celery -l INFO"
ExecReload=/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/celery multi restart 3
ExecStop=/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollageenv/bin/celery multi stopwait 3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: celery user doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

For `celery multi` I think it is better to use `Type=oneshot`. Celery can start many workers processes and each will have its own PID.

I start my `celery` like this:

```
celery multi start 2\
-A my_app_name\
--uid=1001 --gid=1001\
-f /var/log/celery/celery.log\
--loglevel="INFO"\
--pidfile:1=/run/celery1.pid\
--pidfile:2=/run/celery2.pid
```

Of course in your case `uid`, `gid` and all paths will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
User=celery
Group=celery
```

to your user and group, in my case:

```
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
```

Comment: Or you can create the celery group and celery user, like it says in the docs :)